# (S)WVP - Vopenka's priciple

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory, large-cardinals

I would like to understand why precisely - in the nice result [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.00284.pdf) on Vopenka's principle - on the 2nd page, in the last but one paragraph it is **enough** that there is an ordinal $\kappa$ and a homomorphism $G(\kappa)\to G(\kappa+1)$? I think that I'm missing something very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWVP says, that the equality $Hom(G(\alpha),G(\alpha'))=\emptyset\Leftrightarrow \alpha<\alpha'$ doesn't hold for any sequence of graphs.
He assumes, that the sequence of graphs fulfills $"\Rightarrow"$ in the definition of SWVP. Then you need to show, that $"\Leftarrow"$ doesn't hold, that means, there are $\alpha<\alpha'$. s.t. there is an homomorphism $G(\alpha)\to G(\alpha')$. He shows that there is an $\kappa$ s.t. there is an homomorphism $G(\kappa)\to G(\kappa+1)$.

Comment: Do you please happen to know how is defined the ordinary VP from $Hom(G(\alpha),G(\alpha'))$ ?